# Can I use one mysql database for two projects?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to make an android app that have two sites, one is for customer and the other one is for driver and operator. I'm a little confused how to do this. I thought I would make two projects but have one database.
How do I do this? Or is there a better way? Please forgive this stupid question. I'm still learning btw.

Comment: Using same databases from different threads can lead up to concurrency, integrity and deadlock issues. It is possible but you have to do it efficiently.

Comment: Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Comment: And yes, you can use one mysql DB for two android applications. Your server API must solve concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

There is NO hard rule.

Largely depends on why or why not?

Architectural Patterns and Design Patterns are not meant for avoiding duplication or tight-coupling. They are not rules. These are very matured well tried and well tested convenience patterns.

Many times there will be redundancy or tight-coupling by policy or by business rule or legislation or efficiencies or to avoid maintenance complexity.

To answer your question…

E.g. You require an application which has large data input say to 10–50 Lakh records per 24 hours. These records need to be processed and reports updated ASAP before the end of Calendar day which is 12 midnight.

It makes sense to have the two different projects with a common database:

Which processes the data and generates reports in the background even possibly based on a scheduler
A UI based application which allows users to input data and view reports.
Something like an email or sms campaign.

In this case both projects will be accessing the same database or databases. You may have master data on an RDBMS server and trasactional data on NoSQL database for analytics and reports etc.

In QA or at the end of delivery you will anyways know what went right or wrong with your architecture and design.

You may want to discuss these things with your applications architect. Have a good academic relation with your applications and solutions architect. It will give you great insights.

Comment: [how do i write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) "Not all questions can or should be answered here"